# Using "across" to change multiple columns in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have 100 columns that are all numeric. The first column is an ID number, which needs to stay numeric, and I need to change the other columns to factors. I have been trying to use the new(ish) `across` function from `dplyr` to do this, but I cannot successfully apply the function to all columns except the first one. From what I've read, I should be able to do the following:

```
df %>% mutate(across(everything(!c(ID)), as.factor))
```

But this gives the error: "Can't subset columns that don't exist. Locations 101, 102, etc. do not exist." What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You may need `across(-ID,  factor)`

Comment: @akrun That gives me the error, "Problem with mutate() input 2. Input 2 must be a vector, not a function."

Comment: This is a full reproducible example that works `iris %>% mutate(across(-Species, as.character)) %>% str`

Comment: Got it - misplaced parenthesis. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the negate (`!`) in `everything`, we just need `-` or as @27 ϕ 9 mentioned `!` also works without the `everything`

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
     mutate(across(-ID, factor))
```

If there are more than one column, wrap it inside `c`

```
df <- df %>%
        mutate(across(-c(ID, ID2), factor))
```